# Golang string concatenation on HTML page

Tags: json, html, go

I have a JSON string which looks like

```
{
    "Id":"1",
    "Name":"haihello"
    "Account": [
        {"Id":"","BankName":"Citi","BankDetails":"wsafa,  asraa","AccNum":"15321"},
        {"Id":"","BankName":" Deutsche","BankDetails":"aaaaa,aaa","AccNum":"14566"}
    ]
}
```

I want to display all the users in the database on a HTML page in table form ("Name", "Has_Account_in").

Note: a person can have multiple Bank accounts.

I am sending this JSON string from my Golang program to a HTML page. On the HTML page I want to concatenate all the **BankName** with a coma and display.

For example:

```
Name             Has_Account_in
haihello         Citi,Deutsche
Jhon             Citi,Swiss,Axis
Bob              Swiss,HDFC,,Deutsche,HDFC
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The JSON string that you have posted contains the data for one user. So you will be sending back an array of such objects from your Golang service to your web page?

Comment: You will need to write JavaScript code on your webpage, to receive this JSON, parse it, and construct a table.

Comment: sounds like you are wanting us to write the code for you.  add some code examples you've tried and come back.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend first parsing the JSON into a go struct, from there it is much easier to manipulate.

[I defined a similar scenario](https://play.golang.org/p/g56TqSH7ta) with a customer who has made purchases at a store. It would be pretty trivial to make a list of customers (each having a list of purchases), I just didn't want to make up that much JSON..

Once you have the struct or struct slice, you can do whatever you would like with the data. It sounds like you are trying to display the information via html - so you should check out golang templates. You can define your html using that syntax, and then fill it with the data from your go struct(s).

[Here is an example/tutorial](https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/07.4.html) for templates in GO that is better than what I could write for you.

Hope this helps!